# Protractor with phantomjs hangs forever

Tags: angularjs, windows, node.js, phantomjs, protractor

Here's my conf file:

```
exports.config = { 
   seleniumServerJar: './selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar', 
  "capabilities": { 
    "browserName": "phantomjs"   
 }, 
 specs: [ 
        "test.js" 
    ], 
    jasmineNodeOpts: { 
        isVerbose: false, 
        showColors: true, 
        includeStackTrace: true 
    }, 
};
```

here's the called test.js .It is against `ng-europe` community site so everybody who wish will be able to run this.I choose it to learn protractor as it is written in angular:

```
describe('test ng-europe', function() { 

        beforeEach(function() { 
                browser.get('http://ngeurope.org'); 
        }); 

         it('should have a title', function() { 
                expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('ng-europe'); 
                element.all(by.repeater('avatar in talk.avatars')).count().then(function(count) { 
                        console.log(count); 
                }); 
        }); 

        it('search something', function() { 
                var search_=element(by.model('speakerq')); 
                var speakers_=element.all(by.repeater('speaker in config.speakers').column('name')); 
                var speakers = $$('div.speaker.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.text-center.ng-scope img.img-responsive.img-thumbnail.img-circle.avatar');
                search_.sendKeys('igor'); 
                expect(speakers.count()).toBe(1); 
                console.log("speakers count" + speakers.count()); 
        }); 

        it('search something else', function() { 
                var search_=element(by.model('talksq')); 
                var talkers = $$('ul.list-unstyled li.ng-scope.ng-binding span.speakers-names.ng-binding'); 
                search_.sendKeys('with'); 
                expect(talkers.count()).toBe(8); 
                console.log("talkers count" + talkers.count()); 
        }); 

        it('click on jobs', function() { 
                var jobs_button=element(by.linkText('Jobs')); 
                jobs_button.click(); 
                var sponsors=$$('div.col-md-4 img.sponsor-logo.gold-sponsor') 
                expect(sponsors.count()).toBe(4);        
        }); 
});
```

And here's how I call this:

```
>protractor conf.js
```

selenium driver is in the same directory node,**%appdata%\npm** is in the path, phantomjs is installed and updated.Everything runs fine if I set the driver to **chrome** or **firefox** but with **phantomjs** the script just hangs forever and nothing happens.No error displayed , nothing.Just this:

```
Starting selenium standalone server... 
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver 
Selenium standalone server started at http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:60324/wd/hub
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to, at least, make it run the tests using:

- `phantomjs` *1.9.7*
- `protractor` *2.0.0*

But, now it throws the following error message right after successfully passed first `it()` block:

> Error: Failed: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Here is the config I've used (several phantomjs helper "tricks" applied):

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60'],

    "capabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        'phantomjs.cli.args': [
            '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',  
            '--web-security=false'
        ]
    },

    specs: [
        "test.js"
    ],

    framework: "jasmine2",

    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,

        defaultTimeoutInterval: 25000
    }
};
```

There are a lot of people asking how to tackle an error like this:

- [PhantomJS sometimes crashes](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/557)
- https://gist.github.com/tfnico/8471223

There are different workarounds suggested but none of them worked for me and other people.

Which leads to the main point of the answer: **why phantomjs in the first place?**

As noted by [`protractor` developers](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/25aec6cac875b8b8e9a11a4cf5099c113359faa6/docs/browser-support.md):

> We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor. There
>   are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving
>   differently from real browsers.

Extending the point.

If the main purpose for using `protractor` is end-to-end testing, then you should definitely rethink your browser choice. End to end tests should imitate a real user of your application which, I'm pretty sure, would not use `phantomjs` to browse your site.

If the reason to choose `phantomjs` is the absence of a real display, you can use virtual one with the help of `xvfb` (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361778/771848)) or run your tests on a remote selenium server, either your own, or provided by [`BrowserStack`](https://www.browserstack.com) or [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/).

Comment: thanks for the exhausting answer! I still cannot run this , but anyway will accept the answer (the only  difference is that my phantom is `v1.98`) . Sauce labs looks promising :-)